# On Amplify Push getting "Packaging lambda failed function failed. Could not find npm executable in the PATH." but NPM is in path

Tags: npm, aws-amplify

When I amplify push I get the error "Packaging lambda failed function failed. Could not find npm executable in the PATH."

which npm returns /usr/local/bin/npm
amplify version 4.41.2

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you have created lambda functions that are not used, do `amplify remove function` and get rid of the unused functions. That's what triggered the same error in my case.